# Using REST api in ActiveMQ

Tags: python, rest, activemq-classic

I have been using ActiveMQ 5.11.x at work for a long time, in particular through python27 + pyactivemq. I'd like to simplify my python code and I thought that it may be a good thing to send and consume messages using the ActiveMQ REST api instead.

However I don't seem to be able even to do the basic tasks. I'm experimenting locally with curl and wget as the webpage http://activemq.apache.org/rest.html suggest, but this webpage is messy and confusing (well, as all ActiveMQ documentation is, frankly).

Only thing that seems to work for me is sending a message to a queue with

```
curl -X POST -u admin:admin http://localhost:8161/api/message/myqueue?type=queue
```

Consuming from the same queue with -X GET method doesn't work, even generating a cookie as suggested in the webpage (multiple consumers are created for every get)
Also can't do anything with topics, both sending and consuming.

Any help on this matter is really appreciated, if someone could post some coherent examples on how to produce/consume queues and topics with curl or similar it would be great.

Comment: Actually. The Rest part is more or less a demo how to use ActiveMQ in a servlet. Using rest to do messaging is also, perhaps not the best of ideas if you don't spend some time thinking about transactionality etc. I would continue with STOMP or what have you.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right. In any case, if I ever manage to solve this "block" issue, I'm sure I will encounter problems when actually transporting payloads. In my project we use MapMessage instead of TextMessage so transporting suff as a JSON payload is definitely a problem. I don't think I will continue my experiment. Thanks for the comment